# Copy files to another folder during check in (TFS Preview)

Tags: tfs, checkin, file-copying

I have the following scenario: The company edits aspx/xml/xslt files and copy manually to the servers in order to publish them. So, no build is done. For the sake of control we've decided to adopt TFS Preview since it tracks the version, who edited and so on. Needless to say, it works like a charm. :)

The problem is that since we are unable to build the apps we can't set a build definition to automate the copy of files to another place which, as I've stated before, is done manually.

My question is: Is it possible to copy the files to another place (a folder in a server or local) **during the check in**? If so, how? (remember, we don't build. so we can't customize the build process...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1) Create a custom check in policy. I'm not familiar with this process enough to give you any pointers, but I believe it can be done.

2) Create a custom build template, and use that for your builds. You should be able to wipe the build template down to nothing, and then only add the copy operation to it. This is probably the route I would take. Get started [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! The check in policy will do it just fine for what we need! :)

Answer (score 0):

You mention you are using TFSPreview, which is hosted on the cloud so it won't be able to access any machines in your network unless you're prepared to open up your firewalls :).

You can copy source controlled files around the TFS Instance ([say into a Source Controlled Drop F[1](https://tfspreview.com/en-us/learn/build/setup-ci-build-in-vs/)) and then check this out after the build completes. 
Start by familiarising yourself with [customising the TFS Build Process](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx).

When you're up to speed, you need to look at adding a "Copy" Activity in the Workflow to move the files to the drop folder.

Comment: Thanks! But we are not building the project since we are unable to do it. If we could, the build process would be already customized. :)
The TFS itself is there only as file repository and version control. We would need to customize the check in. THAT is the problem.

Comment: You might need to create your own build process. The just copies files around then. I have less info on how to do that though.